# Rescue disk is unable to see the lvm physical volumes

Tags: linux, lvm

We have a system that is setup to have a redundant filesystem including the boot partitions. We are at a point now that the system does not boot properly on either boot partitions. When booting, it says it can't locate the volume group.

When booting on the CentOS rescue disk, fdisk -l sees all the partitions:

1st Raid has
/dev/sda1 Boot
/dev/sda2 swap
/dev/sda3 LVM

2nd Raid has
/dev/sdc1 Boot
/dev/sdc2 swap
/dev/sdc3 LVM

There is also a 3rd LVM on a raid disk that is there for only data. This is not being read either.

When running pvscan, it says "No matching physical volumes found". Is there a way to see why it does not recognize the LVM physical volumes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> vgscan -vvvv

will give you very extensive output about why vgscan considers any specific volume being part of a volume group. You also could run `pvs -a` to see a summary of your physical volumes alongside with volume group assignments.

> vgscan -vvvv output for one of the partitions:

```
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO /dev/sdc3: size is 3772817055 sectors 
Closed /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdc3: size is 3772817055 sectors 
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO O_DIRECT /dev/sdc3: block size is 512 bytes 
Closed /dev/sdc3 Using /dev/sdc3 
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO O_DIRECT /dev/sdc3: block size is 512 bytes 
/dev/sdc3: No label detected
Closed /dev/sdc3
```

> pvs -a didn't reveal anything. All physical volumes listed without a volume group assignment

"no label detected" sounds pretty sad. You are sure that it is a LVM2 partition and not, say, a partition used by md-raid? You could check using `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc3`. And please post `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`

> Yes I'm sure it is an LVM2 partition. The mdadm command gives "No md superblock detectd on /dev/sdc3"
>   The fdisk says /dev/sdc3 is a Linux LVM partition.

Ah, then you will be in the lucky position (irony here, sorry) to try LVM recovery due to presumably damaged data structures. There is a [howto about LVM recovery](http://www.howtoforge.com/recover_data_from_raid_lvm_partitions) which might give you a starting point - try loading your VG configuration either from the disk itself (using `dd if=/dev/sdc3 bs=512 count=255 skip=1`) or from the */etc/lvm/backup* folder of your former root filesystem (which I understand is on /dev/sdc1) into */etc/lvm/backup/* and re-issuing the `vgscan` command.

> I tried that on both sda3 and sdc3 (as you can see, I have 3 lvm partitions to do this too) and they all result in binary files in the output text file. 
>   Ok, correction. There is some lvm meta data in the file, but it's several bytes into the file. I'm looking through the data, but it looks correct. I will keep trying to go through that restore process.

This is expected - both, VG and LV configs is cleartext within binary structures.

> I ended up using a slightly modified process than what was outlined here. I ended up making a cfgbackup file from the byte data in the LVM, do a pvcreate, then a vgcfgrestore. After that, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: vgscan -vvvv output for one of the partitions:
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO
/dev/sdc3: size is 3772817055 sectors
Closed /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3: size is 3772817055 sectors
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO O_DIRECT
/dev/sdc3: block size is 512 bytes
Closed /dev/sdc3
Using /dev/sdc3
Opened /dev/sdc3 RO O_DIRECT
/dev/sdc3: block size is 512 bytes
/dev/sdc3: No label detected
Closed /dev/sdc3

Comment: pvs -a didn't reveal anything. All physical volumes listed without a volume group assignment.

Comment: "no label detected" sounds pretty sad. You are sure that it is a LVM2 partition and not, say, a partition used by md-raid? You could check using `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc3`. And please post `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is an LVM2 partition. The mdadm command gives "No md superblock detectd on /dev/sdc3"

Comment: The fdisk says /dev/sdc3 is a Linux LVM partition. I can't past in the exact text since my connection to the machine is a vnc connection to a terminal and won't let me paste. I'll put up a screen shot though.

Comment: screen shot here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/macanthony/5784545659/

Comment: Ah, then you will be in the lucky position (irony here, sorry) to try LVM recovery due to presumably damaged data structures. There is a [howto about LVM recovery](http://www.howtoforge.com/recover_data_from_raid_lvm_partitions) which might give you a starting point - try loading your VG configuration either from the disk itself (using `dd if=/dev/sdc3 bs=512 count=255 skip=1`) or from the /etc/lvm/backup folder of your former root filesystem (which I understand is on /dev/sdc1) into /etc/lvm/backup/<vgname> and re-issuing the vgscan command.

Comment: I tried that on both sda3 and sdc3 (as you can see, I have 3 lvm partitions to do this too) and they all result in binary files in the output text file.

Comment: Ok, correction. There is some lvm meta data in the file, but it's several bytes into the file. I'm looking through the data, but it looks correct. I will keep trying to go through that restore process.

Comment: This is expected - both, VG and LV configs is cleartext within binary structures.

Comment: BTW, sda1 is the /boot mount so I can't actually put this on my /etc in my file structure (since /etc is actually on the lvm partition). I'm going to try using the /etc of the rescue disk I'm booting from. Let me know if you think there is an issue with this.

Comment: No, you shouldn't mount /dev/sda1 as /etc. I just assumed that /dev/sda1 would be your root fs (and not just /boot) and thus contain the original /etc/lvm/backup directory of your host. If it is not accessible and you do not have any backups, just extract the config data from the drives as described in the guide and place it in your rescue system's /etc/lvm/backup directory.

Comment: I ended up using a slightly modified process than what was outlined here. I ended up making a cfgbackup file from the byte data in the LVM, do a pvcreate, then a vgcfgrestore. After that, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've added your comments and my replies to the answer to preserve it in a better readable form for the posterity. Hope you do not mind.